# Android styles not overriding correctly

Tags: android

I'm trying to set up theming in my Android app but the style tag inheritance doesn't appear to be working properly. The app is using the value given to the parent, not the child.

I have the following in values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
</style>

<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

I'm applying the theme here:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    ...
}
```

I'm expecting elements that use the colorAccent tag to show up as blue, but they're showing up as green. There is nothing else in the app that references the style tag BaseAppTheme directly.

Comment: Your code is conceptually correct but I think you just have inheritance mistake. Your `AppTheme` is based on `BaseRewriteTheme` which is not provided here. I can imagine it was supposed to be `BaseAppTheme`

Comment: You are correct. However, it was just a typo after replacing tag names with generic ones. I edited the post to fix the mistake. I still have the problem described above. Thanks!

Comment: Are you supporting multiple screen sizes/densities etc? May be you're changing style in one place but instead device takes from another place? (in other words how many styles.xml do you have in your project)

Comment: I do have a v21\styles.xml file in my workspace, but it does not have any related styles or attributes

Answer (score 0):

The theme should be created before the onCreated been called. As in the following code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    ...
}
```

Comment: and he's calling it before, as he stated. moreover you don't have to call it before super

Comment: I tried setting the theme prior to calling super.onCreate(Bundle bundle), but experienced the same results.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I was overriding `AppTheme` in *values* > *style.xml* in my flavour. But the Android version in the device where I was executing the application was higher than API 26.

What's with that? There was already an `AppTheme` in *values-v26* > *style.xml* in the main flavour. So I only had to create a *values-v26* > *style.xml* with the `AppTheme` in my flavour's *res* and that was it.